# IOS pin user interface for Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[image]

I need a UI like this for my app. How can I implement this using Angular JS only.

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Comment: I have not started anything...looking for leads to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a directive similar to this for otp inputs.
This is for angular 1

[OTP Input Directive](https://github.com/amstel91/otp-input-directive)

In controller:

```
$scope.otpInput={
        size:6,
        type:"text",
        onDone: function(value){
            console.log(value);
        },
        onChange: function(value){
            console.log(value);
        }
    };
```

In HTML:

```
<div otp-input-directive options="otpInput"></div>
```

Here is the plunker for the same:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eCHuJT?p=preview

Comment: I will try this out. Thanks for quick response.